# Unary operator in .reduce() function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was reading a medium article and came across this code. It returns the object with the most experienced pilot using `.reduce()` . I can’t wrap my head around the expression `(oldest.years || 0)` . Why not just use `(oldest.years )` ?

```
var pilots = [
  {
    id: 10,
    name: "Poe Dameron",
    years: 14,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Temmin 'Snap' Wexley",
    years: 30,
  },
  {
   id: 41,
   name: "Tallissan Lintra",
   years: 16,
 },
 {
   id: 99,
   name: "Ello Asty",
   years: 22,
 }
   ];

var mostExpPilot = pilots.reduce(function (oldest, pilot) {
  return (oldest.years || 0) > pilot.years ? oldest : pilot;
}, {});

console.log(mostExpPilot);
```

Comment: Because for some reasons, `oldest.years` could be `undefined`

Comment: *"Why not just use `(oldest.years )` ?"* Because the initial value of the object is `{}`, which has no `years` property.

Comment: this is a good example for using reduce without start value.

Comment: @NinaScholz - So long as the array isn't possibly empty, or you guard against it before the call. It's an even better example of when to just use a loop. ;-)

Comment: You would not need to do it if it were initialized with a default value `pilots.reduce(function(){...}, { years: 0 });` or just `pilots.reduce(function(){...});`

Answer (score 3):

When we look at the documentation of `Array.reduce` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#parameters we can see that this is because the example code has an `initialValue` of `{}` which has no `years` property.

Same would be:

```
var mostExpPilot = pilots.reduce(function (oldest, pilot) {
  return oldest.years > pilot.years ? oldest : pilot;
}, { years: 0});
```